# Number of Views Error after 1K views

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When a question has been viewed more than a thousand times the "K" gets put before views rather than after the number. Example: 2 // kviews rather than 2K // views.

Comment: we're measuring kilo-views....apparently

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29544/kviews-should-be-k-views

Comment: See also: [Can questions with thousands of views and votes look that way on the main page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153339/1438 "No official response yet.").

Answer (score 1):

Much to my surprise. We are in fact measuring kilo-views.

Here is the canonical Meta Stackoverflow posts on it: [1 kviews—shouldn't kviews be singular?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74341/1-kviewsshouldnt-kviews-be-singular)

So this is an intentional design decision rather than a bug. I'll tag it [status-bydesign](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: Oh, ok. That still seems odd to me. But whatever.

Comment: think of it as a metric prefix on views. You wouldn't have 1k meters. You have 1 kilometer.

Comment: Yeah, but you wouldn't say 1 kmiles you would say 1k miles. I think its kinda an odd prefix.

Comment: @jcoat: I wonder if this is one of the things that be be fiddled with in the design of the graduated site...

Comment: @JonEricson not likely. As that's part of the engine not the css. (for reference, RPG has kviews even in their new design)

Comment: Boo!  (I'm voting down the answer because, even though it's correct, I don't like the status quo.)

Comment: inconsistent. That's not good. Voted up your meta post.

Comment: Upvoting because of correctness and explanation. Booyah @JonEricson... :P

Comment: meta upvotes...yeah! more reps....oh wait :(

Comment: I noticed this too and thought it was a font problem on my computer. But doesn't it make more sense to say 1K views instead of 1 kviews? Putting a K after a number is pretty universal but a k before some arbitrary unit not so much. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29544/kviews-should-be-k-views